# Why does (only) the code formatting sometimes not work in a question/answer?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Usually, when **selecting the code** (of course, in edit  mode) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, or <kbd>{}</kbd>, the selection is correctly formatted as code:

```
Sub Foo()
    'Whatever in here...
End Sub
```

But sometimes, the above way of formatting, simply does not work! The code is moved for one Tab space, but it looks messed up.

In such a situation I use the next (less elegant) way, using ``:

`Sub Foo() 'Whatever in here... End Sub`

Is it a trick, something to be known, in order to avoid such a behavior?

I searched for such a clarification, but I could not find anything conclusive. A link to a place supplying a solution for the above described issue will be good enough.

Edited:

Using ``` on the lines in front and after the code:

```
    Sub Foo()
        'Whatever in here...
    End Sub
```

Comment: use three ``` one line before and one line after the code block.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Thanks! I will edit my question and experiment it. But One character before plus another one after, meant two... Where to put the third one? :)

Comment: no use three together on the line before and three more on the line after: ``` code ```

Comment: @Scott Craner: **Yes!** this was the trick! Thanks! If you will place an answer, I will mark it as accepted one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting tells you all that and more...

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: Thanks! I will study it...

Comment: @FaneDuru also with those you can influence the language formatting  \`\`\`python code \`\`\`  for example. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: The (canonical) one with the most detailed information is *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)*

Answer (score 6):

> But sometimes, the above way of formatting, simple does not work!

What I see happening in the Suggested Edit queue, when people try to fix broken code formatting is:

- There isn't a line break between regular text and the code so the code formatting is broken.

  ```
  It looks like this:
      code is indented but not formatted correctly
  ```

  ```
  Instead of like this:

      code is formatted
  ```
- Sometimes, selecting the blank space above the code in addition to the code itself and then trying to format that throws things off. I'm not sure why but I've seen it get confused as to whether it should be formatting or un-formatting the code.
- It doesn't play nicely with lists. Note that I had to use `<pre>` tags in the first bullet point and it still isn't indented as if it's in the list. Putting code in a list is hard to get right.

Comment: Re *"It doesn't play nicely with lists."*: Indeed. The workaround is to use [an external text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany).

Comment: @CodyGray, you just made my day with that edit, I have been looking for so long on how to properly put code block into bulleted lists, without `pre`. Is there an article or meta post somewhere about this?